# String taken from database table post_meta is showing HTML tags on Frontend

Tags: wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type

I have saved a string in post_meta table in wordpress database with html entities like-

`<p>Hello <b>Shashank</b>, I have an idea.</p>`

When I get this string on frontend using function

`get_post_meta(get_the_id(),field_name, true)`.

It echoes string with HTML entities as same as it stores in DB.

But I want to show this sting as "Hello **Shashank**, I have an idea."

How can I do this.?

Comment: In other words, how do you display it, rendering the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

try following code snippet

```
<?php
$text_to_display = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),field_name, true);
echo strip_tags($text_to_display);
?>
```

Comment: Hello Ajith..I have used this function but it did not worked.